# Регулярные выражения, работа с числовыми данными(статический класс Math.PI)

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Нужно чтобы пользователь ввел число, которое будет значить количество символов после запятой числа PI. У меня не получается сделать это с числом 4 почему-то. Ну и вообще, не все числа в диапазоне от 0-14 работают корректно.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var numberPi = Math.PI.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine("Digits affter dot:");
    string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
    string newtext4 = Regex.Replace(numberPi.ToString(), @"(\d{"+userInput+"})", string.Empty);
    Console.WriteLine("The Pi is:{0}",newtext4.ToString()); 
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Потому что у Вас кавычек не хватает - и форматированный код в вопросе довольно явно это показывает.

Comment: да, простите, после знака @ должен быть, но это не решает проблему, к сожалению.

Comment: А зачем вам регулярка. Вы знаете что в начале 2 символа `3.` значит можете просто взять фиксированно строку запрошенной длины +2

Comment: я хотел попробовать попрактиковаться с регулярными, и взял для примера число ПИ, может не совсем удачно для начала, но интересно

Comment: "не все числа в диапазоне от 0-14 работают корректно" - Вы ведь хотите, чтобы Вам помогли? Если у Вас есть данные о том, какие числа работают, а какие нет, - зачем темнить?

Comment: И где собственно ваша регулярка проверяет на точку например. \d{1} в этой регулярке у вас даст цифру перед точкой

Comment: И вообще, вы же replece применяете, значит вырезаете то, что регулярка нашла. Когда пользователь задаст число 2 то из строки `3.141592` регулярка найдет первое подошедшее, т.е. 14. результат будет `3.1592`

Comment: блин))) ну да по сути) то есть, сначала нужно убрать все символы после запятой, а потом выбрать уже, сколько нужно добавить?

Comment: Я бы, если ваш диалект регулярок не позволяет отметить точку начала совпадения (`\K`) забрал в скобки все что надо оставить и подставил бы это. т.е. если изначально число `3.141592` и хотят 2 цифры после запятой, то регулярка `(\d\.\d{2})\d+` и меняем это на `$1` т.е. на то, что захватили первые скобки

Comment: Если же `\K` у вас работает то проще: `\d\.\d{2}\K.*` меняем на ничего

Comment: честно - пока сложновато:) ну я понимаю немного, скорее всего нужно побольше учить, перед тем как задавать вопросы), но спасибо большое, что откликнулись!!!

Answer (score 3):

Задача отображения нужного количества строк после запятой решается родными средствами, без регулярки:

```
Console.WriteLine("Digits affter dot:");
string userInput = Console.ReadLine();

Console.WriteLine(Math.PI.ToString("n" + userInput));
```

nX, где X - число - это [стандартная строка форматирования](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx) для чисел, позволяющая вывести нужное количество знаков после запятой.

Если уж очень хочется решить это регуляркой, нужно матчить отдельно ту часть, которую хотелось бы оставить, при замене оставлять именно ее:

```
var numberPi = Math.PI.ToString();
Console.WriteLine("Digits affter dot:");
string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
string newtext4 = Regex.Replace(numberPi.ToString(), @"(\d\.\d{" + userInput + @"})\d*", "$1");
Console.WriteLine("The Pi is:{0}", newtext4.ToString());
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Спасибо!!!) это тот вариант, который я и хотел получить в результате!!!
Буду теперь разбирать что да как)

Comment: @Vlad_Kompanets только осторожнее - не во всех культурах . - это разделитель дробной части. поэтому лучше не парсить числа регулярками.

Comment: @Vlad_Kompanets, более того, в наших культурах разделителем дробной части является запятая.